# WPF Control no connection to class

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to create a control in WPF for a button that lies beneath a border, as I prefer the buttons to have rounded corners. I have created a ResourceDictionary with the necessary code and then incorporated it into my view, which worked successfully. Next, I wanted to be able to pass the color dynamically for the border, specifying the color I'd like the border to have.Here is my Class Code:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace GetraenkespenderDesign.Controls.CustomButtonWithBorder
{
    public class CustomButtonWithBorder : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalBackgroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NormalBackgroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomButtonWithBorder));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverBackgroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HoverBackgroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomButtonWithBorder));

        public Brush NormalBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(NormalBackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NormalBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public Brush HoverBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(HoverBackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HoverBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        static CustomButtonWithBorder()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomButtonWithBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomButtonWithBorder)));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Resource Dictionary Code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GetraenkespenderDesign.Controls.CustomButtonWithBorder">

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomButtonWithBorder" x:Key="CustomBorderButton">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="NormalBackgroundColor" Value="#4e99ff"/>
        <Setter Property="HoverBackgroundColor" Value="#000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomButtonWithBorder">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            Margin="10"
                            Panel.ZIndex="1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding NormalBackgroundColor}">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding NormalBackgroundColor}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding HoverBackgroundColor}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thanks for youre Help

My Errors:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XDG0008 The name 'CustomButtonWithBorder' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:GetraenkespenderDesign.Controls.CustomButtonWithBorder.

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XDG0012 The element 'NormalBackgroundColor' was not recognized, or it cannot be accessed. GetraenkespenderDesign

Both from the ResourceDictionary

Comment: The error will usually disappear when you build the project. If not verify the namespace alias definition of local. In case your code resides in a different assembly you must fully qualify the namespace alias including the assembly. Also you must remove the x:Key attribute from the Style and move it to the Generic.xaml file. This is because you were overriding the default style in the static constructor of your control.

Comment: Not that using NormalBackgroundColor to define the button's background breaks the inherited berhavior as you would naturally use the Background property to do modify the background brush. NormalBackgroundColor property is not needed. You should drop it. Simple toggle between Backgroung and the hover brush.

Comment: This error can also occur when the build of that type fails. Consult the Visual Studio error list window for information.